# Android SQLite Database : Cannot resolve constructor

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create a simple SQLite database in android. I am following [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/). But the code gives this error **"Cannot resolve constructor Contact()"**. Below is the code for DatabaseHandler.java. I have pointed out the line where the error occurs so it's easy to understand.

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Usama on 10/7/2017.
 */

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "favouritesmanager";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "favourites";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
    private static final String KEY_ADRESS = "adress";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + KEY_ADRESS + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Adding new contact
    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone Number
        values.put(KEY_ADRESS, contact.getAdress()); //address

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Contact contact = new Contact();   <<<< HERE IS THE ERROR
                contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                contact.setAdress(cursor.getString(3));

                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

}
```

and here is the contact.java class

```
public class Contact {

    int _id;
    String _name;
    String _phone_number;
    String _adress;

    // constructor
    public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number, String adress){
        this._id = id;
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
        this._adress = adress;
    }

   // constructor
    public Contact(String name, String _phone_number, String adress){
        this._name = name;
        this._phone_number = _phone_number;
        this._adress = adress;
    }

    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getName(){
        return this._name;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setName(String name){
        this._name = name;
    }

    // getting phone number
    public String getPhoneNumber(){
        return this._phone_number;
    }

    // setting phone number
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
        this._phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    //getting adress
    public String getAdress(){

        return this._adress;
    }

    //setting adress
    public void setAdress(String adresstowrite){
        this._adress = adresstowrite;
    }
}
```

Any fixes for this error please?

Comment: You have two constructors but neither is empty. They both require having values passed to them. Create an empty one or pass the necessary values to one of them depending on your needs.

Comment: At the beginning of the tutorial you linked, you will see `// Empty constructor
    public Contact(){
         
    }`

Comment: Thnks @codeMagic, It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create empty constructor.

```
// Empty constructor
public Contact(){

}
```